# Pyopencl array sum to add an array

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

I am new to opencl and pyopencl. I am trying to write a basic program to add. I came across [this](https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/array.html#pyopencl.array.sum) documentation and tried this small code in python. Obviously, it is not working.

```
import pyopencl as cl
import pyopencl.tools
import pyopencl.array
import numpy

context = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(context)

h_a = numpy.random.rand(3,3)
d_a = cl.Buffer(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY | 
cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=h_a)
print cl.array.sum(d_a, dtype=None, queue=queue)
```

As you can assess, I am not sure about how to use those predefined functions.

Answer (score 2):

My PyOpenCl tutorial has an array sum example with inline comments explaining what each line does:  https://github.com/benshope/PyOpenCL-Tutorial

Try running that, I hope it is helpful!